# Setting up sunbird-telemetry Kafka DRUID and superset

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, druid

I am trying to create a analytics dashboard based from mobile events. I want to dockerize all the components to containers in docker and deploy it in localhost and create an analytical dashboard.

1. Sunbird telemetry https://github.com/project-sunbird/sunbird-telemetry-service
2. Kafka https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker
3. Druid https://github.com/apache/incubator-druid/tree/master/distribution/docker
4. Superset https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset

What i did

**Druid**

1. I executed the command `docker build -t apache/incubator-druid:tag -f distribution/docker/Dockerfile .`
2. I executed the command `docker-compose -f distribution/docker/docker-compose.yml up`
3. After everything get executed open http://localhost:4008/ and see DRUID running

It takes **3.5 hours** to complete both build and run

**Kafka**

1. Navigate to kafka folder
2. `docker-compose up -d` executed this command

**Issue**
When we execute druid a zookeeper starts running, and when we start kafka the docker file starts another zookeeper and i cannot establish a connection between kafka and zookeeper. 
After i start sunbird telemetry and tries to create topic and connect kafka from sunbird its not getting connected.

I dont understand what i am doing wrong.
**Can we tell kafka to share the zookeeper started by DRUID**.  I am completed new to this environment and these stacks. 
I am studying this stacks. Am i doing something wrong. Can anybody point out how to properly connect kafka and druid over docker.

**Note:- I am running all this in my mac**

My kafka compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: **localhost ip**
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: **localhost ip**:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

[image: I have two zookeeper running]

Comment: Please show your compose file

Comment: @cricket_007 I have updated my kafka docker compose file

Comment: @GeorgeThomas the "KAFKA_(...)" envs will not work in your case if you build the Kafka image yourself. Yesterday I explained that in my answer how exactly these settings are applied. The easiest solution would be to:
1. Modify the server.properties file and build the image yourself.
2. Use a prepared image that supports configuration via env variables.

Comment: So basically i can use a single yml file to start all kafka druid and sunbird and all the configuration for connecting each of them can be specified in this single docker-compose.yml file itself

Comment: @Dth Env vars will work. That compose file is just cloned from that repo. The image there does support the variables. But yes, using the actual image in DockerHub makes more sense than building it

Comment: @GeorgeThomas Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we tell kafka to share the zookeeper started by DRUID

You would put all services in the same compose file.

Druids kafka connection is listed here

https://github.com/apache/incubator-druid/blob/master/distribution/docker/environment#L31

You can set KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT to the same address, yes

---

For example, downloading the file above and adding Kafka to the Druid Compose file...

```
version: "2.2"

volumes:
  metadata_data: {}
  middle_var: {}
  historical_var: {}
  broker_var: {}
  coordinator_var: {}
  overlord_var: {}
  router_var: {}

services:

  # TODO: Add sunbird

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - metadata_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=FoolishPassword
      - POSTGRES_USER=druid
      - POSTGRES_DB=druid

  # Need 3.5 or later for container nodes
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: zookeeper:3.5
    environment:
      - ZOO_MY_ID=1

  druid-coordinator:
    image: apache/incubator-druid
    container_name: druid-coordinator
    volumes:
      - coordinator_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "3001:8081"
    command:
      - coordinator
    env_file:
      - environment

  # renamed to druid-broker
  druid-broker: 
    image: apache/incubator-druid
    container_name: druid-broker
    volumes:
      - broker_var:/opt/druid/var
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
      - postgres
      - druid-coordinator
    ports:
      - "3002:8082"
    command:
      - broker
    env_file:
      - environment

 # TODO: add other Druid services

 kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092"
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181/kafka  # This is the same service that Druid is using
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can we tell kafka to share the zookeeper started by DRUID

Yes, as there's a `zookeeper.connect` setting for Kafka broker that specifies the Zookeeper address to which Kafka will try to connect. How to do it depends entirely on the docker image you're using. For example, one of the popular images [wurstmeister/kafka-docker](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker) does this by mapping all environmental variables starting with KAFKA_ to broker settings and adds them to server.properties, so that `KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT` becomes a `zookeeper.connect` setting. I suggest taking a look at the official [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) to see what else you can configure.

> and when we start kafka the docker file starts another zookeeper

This is your issue. It's the docker-compose file that starts Zookeeper, Kafka, and configures Kafka to use the bundled Zookeeper. You need to modify it, by removing the bundled Zookeeper and configuring Kafka to use a different one. Ideally, you should have a single docker-compose file that starts the whole setup.